# finding substring in string not returning true python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, substring

I have these tags which I am returning from a web scraping tool as a part of a CLI application I'm making, I'm trying to see if a substring from the tag contains a line from my wordlist. I have tried to manually cast both values to strings but for some reason, nothing happens and the substring is never found in the string

I have tried using the method below and the 'in' operator but I haven't had any success

here is the method I am using

```py
for tag in inputs:
    for line in input_wordlist:
        print(tag,line)
        if tag.find(str(line)): # check here if the substring is in the string
            print('YES THIS MATCHES')
            vulns.append(line) #add the vulnerability to the list
```

here is an example of the two values i'm comparing
left: the tag as the string
right: the line from the wordlist i'm using as the substring

```
<input id="q-universal-search" type="hidden" value=""/>     hidden
```

Comment: Are `tag` and `line` variables strings? Try `if line.strip() in tag:`

Comment: What are 'tag' and 'line'? Are you using BeatifulSoup or something similar?

Comment: @Roy2012 yes I am using Beautiful soup, my apologies for not clarifying, line is referencing a line in my text files that I am pulling my substrings from

Comment: and what is 'tag'? Is it a BS element?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I was able to use line.rstrip() to match the substring and the string, I had an extra \n in every line I hadn't removed in the word list, if you'd like to post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @monsterpiece Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your output of `print(tag,line)`:

```
<input id="q-universal-search" type="hidden" value=""/>     hidden
```

It seems that `line` variable has some whitespaces that needs to be trimmed.

Try `if line.strip() in tag:` or `if line.rstrip() in tag:` to get the match.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if substring in line` form of if. Like this

```
for tag in inputs:
    for line in input_wordlist:
        print(tag,line)
        if line in tag: # check here if the substring is in the string

            print('YES THIS MATCHES')
            vulns.append(line) #add the vulnerability to the list
```

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately nothing happens and the substring isn't recognized

Comment: Please, try that piece of code 
`sub = 'is';
line = 'some tag is hidden';
print(sub in line) # prints True`;
It works fine. I think the problem is in the values of variables such as tag and line.